# Code prettifying disappearing and reappearing? (may only affect IE 8.)

Tags: support

**[Edit]** I first noticed this issue while working on a Python thread, but later I discovered it also affected a C# thread. So it was bigger than just Python (I changed the title for the sake of SEO). I was using IE 8 when I experienced the issue. Meanwhile, I found code prettifying worked in Firefox, and later, it returned to IE 8. ...hmm?

If I catch it again, I'll use Fiddler to see if any JavaScript libs are 404 (though that would be obvious and affect alot of people). The SE network implements [Google Code Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), and I know Google is dropping IE 8 support all over the place. So it may just be that IE 8 support is waning---and really that's expected, and ultimately a non-issue. On the other hand, something about code syntax highlighting [may just be intermittant](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/code-styling-broken).

**[original post]**

I reviewed [the meta post discussing how to ensure code blocks in a post get proper syntax formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting). However, [I created a python question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/gdal-and-python-how-to-get-coordinates-for-all-cells-having-a-specific-value) and all the line breaks and spacing are stripped out.

The question is tagged for python (though, not "py", as the meta post implies it should be, however "py" isn't an existing GISSE tag and it seems redundant to create it). So while I think I built it correctly, I'm just curious if there is something I'm overlooking that is causing the .py code to get trimmed.

It definitely makes it harder for folks to "see at a glance" anything that might be wrong in the code. Also, if someone copy/pastes the code into their editor, they will have to go to the trouble to clean it before they could even run it. So I'd definitely like to fix the py code in that post if possible.

Thanks! elrobis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akk.. the answer is, the code formatting won't work in IE 8. I opened the thread in a recent install of FireFox and bingo, it's as it should be.

[image]

Comment: The formatting support has since returned to IE 8---so it's not a hard and fast *"won't work"*. Next time it happens I'll watch Fiddler and see if some `.js` libs are 404, etc.